# Find the best match on multiple keywords with regular expression in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to use regular expression in JS to check if the content of an array could match a specific string. The string could be composed of many words, so do the content's array.
My problem is :

```
var myQuery = "I am looking for the red bike";
var myArray = [{kid:24,keyword:"red"}, {kid:32,keyword:"bike"}, {kid:51,keyword:"red bike"}];
```

In that case, I don't want to get only "red" or "bike" but "red bike" because it's the best match.
For now I reverted the request, but it's not concluant:

```
myArray.some(function (el) {
    var myRegEx = new RegExp(el.keyword, "gi");
    if (myRegEx.test(myQuery)) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

It matches on "red".
The function should give me "red" only if my query would have been :

```
var myQuery = "I am looking for the red car";
```

So I'm really not used to regEx, so if anybody could help me, It would be very nice.

Comment: Have you considered to use a larger function, using seperate reg-ex testers? I'm thinking of using a series of if-statements. `if MyText contains 'red', add red to $Result. If MyText contains 'bike', add bike to $Result ...`

Comment: It doesn't look like a very persistant solution, isn't it ? As I understand your idea, it wouldn't be possible to combine a lot of different query, and if I have an array of 4000 items, it would be a nightmare....

Comment: I've set a temporary solution that seems to do the job for now. I'm checking all found results and comparing their length. If I only keep the longer keyword, that will mean that the parameter is the combined one : `if(myRegEx.test(myQuery)){if(el.keyword.length>answer.length){answer = el.keyword;}}` . But if there is a cleaner solution, I'm still up to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) implementation, i.e calculate the difference or distance between two strings (`myQuery` vs each items `keyword`) and then sort the array and return the `keyword` with the lowest distance as best match.

You can find a Levenshtein javascript implementation [**here**](https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927) (have not tested how good it is compared to other)

```
var myQuery = "I am looking for the red bike";
var myArray = [{kid:24,keyword:"red"}, {kid:32,keyword:"bike"}, {kid:51,keyword:"red bike"}];

function bestMatch() {
   var temp = myArray.map(function(item) {
     item.distance = getEditDistance(myQuery, item.keyword)
     return item;
   })
   temp.sort(function(a,b) {
     if (a.distance < b.distance) return -1
     else if (a.distance > b.distance) return 1
     else return 0;
   })
   return temp[0].keyword
}

console.log('Best matching keyword is :', bestMatch());
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hoo207o3/**

Comment: I've never heard about Levenshtein distance. I'll have a look. Thank you.